# Почему не работает middleware?

Tags: laravel

При переходе в админка Laravel, мне выдает две одинаковые ошибки:
`syntax error, unexpected token "return"`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CheckuserPermission
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Auth()->user()->hasPermAnyWay($perm){
            abort(404)
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CheckUserRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Auth->user()->hasRole($role)){
            abort(404);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас в `CheckuserPermission` не хватает точки с запятой `abort(404);`.

Comment: теперь мне выдает ошибку `syntax error, unexpected token ";"`

Comment: `if(!Auth()->user()->hasPermAnyWay($perm)` -- закрывающую скобку в условии забыли, должно быть `if(!Auth()->user()->hasPermAnyWay($perm))`

Comment: Я заметил это. Все равно ничего не работает. Проблема в чем-то другом